# crash dependent on the compiler that happens before the main

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded

I'm working on a project involving an embedded device powered by ARM processor.
I'm compiling the following code both with GCC and [RVCT5](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.faqs/kiengHK1aXx8Am.html)

With GCC I have no compiler warning and the program runs with no problem.

With RVCT5 I don't have compiler warning either but the program crashes in loop

I isolated the crash but I'm clueless on its resolution.

RVCT5 seems to be unable to resolve the address of a callback function that I need to pass as argument to a function.

main.c

```
#include "net_test.h"
void main( int argc, char **argv ) 
{
   printf("TASK1 %p \r\n",&msgTask1); //this is ok
   //printf("TASK2 %p \r\n",&msgTask2); //this crashes
}
```

net.c

```
#include "net_test.h"
INT32 msgTask1(INT32 type, INT32 param1, INT32 param2)
{
  //omissis
}
```

parser.c

```
#include "net_test.h"
INT32 msgTask2(INT32 type, INT32 param1, INT32 param2)
{
  //omissis
}
```

net_test.h

```
INT32 msgTask1(INT32 type, INT32 param1, INT32 param2);
INT32 msgTask2(INT32 type, INT32 param1, INT32 param2);
```

If in my code I uncomment the row printing the address of msgTask2, **the software can't even run the main**. This can be demonstrated both because I don't see the row for msgTask1, and using hardware ARM debugger the application goes on vector catch but the instruction pointer doesn't refer to the main.

From my point of view, there is some error in initializing the function.
I read something about the static initialization order fiasco, but I don't know if this is the case. I'm declaring the functions inside the header that is included in both the source files.

I thought this could be an issue related to memory occupancy, and I tried to increase the stack size available to the application. I also tried to comment away part of the code to reach a stable condition but nothing worked.

Any clue on what I could investigate?

Comment: Don't you have the possibility to examine, which (assembler) instruction exactly leads to the crash (including register context etc)? This is very important for embedded development.

Comment: Though it shouldn't matter, you don't need the `&` in `printf(...,,&msgTask1);` The compiler will (should) already provide the address.

Comment: *crashes in loop* - what does that mean? What happens if you use the debugger and break on `main`? If that doesn't work, it's probably *crt* that has some issue. Can you try to be more precise in your question - listing facts, memory location contents, backtraces etc. Assumptions don't help much, since they can be wrong and send people answering on a wrong track.

Comment: shouldnt need to use a debugger a disassembly should suffice, can you please post the disassembly of each compilers output?

Comment: The code that runs before main is available to you - in fact most often it is required that you have _written it_ if it is a custom board.  It may be in assembler or C, but is no less debuggable.  Place a break-point at the reset vector and start from there.  We cannot debug your start-up code for you if it is not presented and its viability and correctness will depend on your hardware which you have not specified. The printf() crash is probably of no interest - more likely the system is compromised before that and the change in code simply changes the symptoms of some non-deterministic error.

Comment: Your start-up code, the linker script, and details of your target hardware (processor, memory availability) etc. would be useful content in this question.  Also your question emphasizes the printf failure which is far less interesting that an empty main not starting.

Comment: Is it actually crashing or is main() just terminating?  If stdout is buffered but main terminates, it is likely that the buffered output will never be output - and the behaviour may plausibly differ between compilers with different start-up/termination code and libraries.  `main()` should not normally terminate in an embedded system - add a `for(;;){}` at the end of `main` to prevent that.

Comment: Using printf modifier `"%p"` with function pointer is undefined behavior. `the software can't even run the main.` - I can guess this is unrelated to the code you provided. I can guess the crash happens because of linker settings, bad debuger settings, bad linking, bad initiliazation and startup routine, there is overflow in stack or RAM or bss or text or data and your debugger can't detect it. How does it crash? Why can't you pinpoint the assembly instruction related to the crash, if you use an debuger?Does it change when you compile a single file, not three? Why are there 3 files?

Comment: Hello everyone! Thanks for the answers, it helped me think about few causes that may cause this problem. Unfortunately I can't provide full debugger log because I'm from QA department, and I don't have a ARM debugger on my own. I will update this thread if we get additional info.

Comment: At the end, I found that a struct was declared as global.
In GCC it was zero initialized by default.
With RVCT, no memory is allocated for it until memset. 
Although if I expected that the application would crash when the structure was being used, it seems that the compiler had troubles in managing memory.